# Hod do I install confluent_kafka in Pydev/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, confluent-platform

I have installed confluent_kafka:

```
 /home/ed/anaconda3/bin/python
>>> import confluent_kafka
```

throws no errors. However Eclipse/PyDev gives:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
ImportError: No module named confluent_kafka
```

I have a 2.7 interpreter above the anaconda3 one in the list of Python interpreters. Could that be the problem and, if so, how do I remove it? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to move interpreters up/down in the list of interpreters in Python (the first one is used by default in launches, although you can configure a different interpreter per-launch or configure a different interpreter for a given project).